# Hive jobs getting stuck after log initialization in a specified queue

Tags: hadoop, hive, mapreduce, hiveql

It seems lack of resources due to other running jobs in the same queue. Is there any work around to priorities some jobs over running jobs in tsame queue to execute first?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [ask]

Answer (score 0):

If you're using YARN to schedule jobs, there is no way to preempt jobs within the same queue.  A workaround is to move the jobs to another queue if you need to free up resources in a particular queue.

YARN also supports reservations (mentioned in [YARN-1051 YARN Admission Control/Planner: enhancing the resource allocation model with time.](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/YARN-1051)) which allows you to reserve vcores for future jobs.  This came in 2.6.0 but most of the documentation is in 2.8.0.

- [Reservation System](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.0/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ReservationSystem.html)
- [Resource Manager REST APIs for Reservations](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerRest.html#Cluster_Reservation_API_List)

Comment: Thanks for your response, but the challenge is that I can not move the jobs in other queue.